# Load in html page with Node

Tags: html, node.js, express, node-modules

I'm very new to node.js - forgive my incompetence.

I have set up a basic node app on my computer's localhost:8080 following w3school's tutorial.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
   res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);
```

This works properly, displaying hello world on my localhost. However, I can't seem to find a way to load in a separate html document that is in the same folder-level. I am trying to do this:

```
var http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
}).listen(8080);
```

I've downloaded express into the master folder, but I am still getting the error, "TypeError: res.render is not a function" in my terminal. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you could also use the Express [static middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) and create a [route method](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) for answering GET requests to your page root by serving the file. Also, to avoid platform-specific issues with file paths, you can use `path.join()`, where `__dirname` sets the absolute path to your working directory.

```
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();    

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

http.createServer(app).listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('HTTP server listening on port 8080');
});
```